# How to update knockoutjs view model on user confirm?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a edit in place section to which I want to add a confirmation of changes before the knockoutjs model is updated.

Here's the jsFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/7v6Dx/7/) of what I have now.
Here's what I would like it to do.

1. User clicks on editable section
2. textbox appears with save/cancel buttons next to it.
3. if user makes a change and clicks save, view model is updated
4. if user makes a change, but decides to keep the original content, they click cancel, view model remains unchanged, texbox is hidden, and editable element remains unchanged.

The behavior of the cancel click is what I'm not sure how to implement. Can anyone suggest how this could be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use custom binding handler for this.
Example http://jsfiddle.net/7v6Dx/10/

**Html**

```
<div>
    <span class="editField">
        <span data-bind="text: Address1">Click here to edit</span>
        <input type="text" data-bind="clickEditor: Address1">
    </span>
</div>​
```

**JavaScript**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.clickEditor = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {        
        var $element = $(element).hide();
        var $text = $element.prev();
        var $buttons = $("<span class='editConfirm'> \
                    <button class='saveEdit' type='button'>Save</button> \
                    <button class='cancelEdit' type='button'>Cancel</button> \
                </span>").hide().insertAfter($element);
        var $editElements = $buttons.add($element);

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $buttons.remove();
        });

        var _toggle = function(edit) {
            $text[edit? 'hide' : 'show']();
            $editElements[edit? 'show' : 'hide']();
        }

        $text.click(function(e) {
            _toggle(true);
        });

        $editElements.find('.saveEdit').click(function() {
            _toggle(false);
            valueAccessor()($element.val());
        });

        $editElements.find('.cancelEdit').click(function() {
            _toggle(false);
            $(element).val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
         });
    }
    , update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).val(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var helpText = "Click here to edit";

    function appViewModel() {
        this.Address1 = ko.observable(helpText);
    }
    ko.applyBindings(appViewModel());

});​
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for creating a complete working example, with a great blend of knockoutjs and jQuery. Lots of new stuff in there, took me a bit of research to figure out what you were doing with the knockoutjs stuff.

Comment: Only thing I missing in my sample is call to addDisposeCallback (this could be important in some scenarios). Edited example.

Comment: @Artem can you pls take a look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35869093/display-data-from-couchdb-with-knockoutjs/35887453#35887453)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking you could probably use a writable computed property to handle this. But it might be easier to just have to separate properties. One property is the real property and the other shadows it. When you bring up the editable section, it's actually bound to the shadow value. When the ok button is clicked, you copy the shadow value to the real value. If cancel is clicked, you do the opposite (copy the real value to the shadow value).

Comment: That's definitely a way to achieve the functionality, but I'm not sure if that's a clean/efficient way to go about it. The plan was to have this save/cancel function on every field, meaning I'd have to have a clone of the whole view model if I took your approach. Could you expand on your first idea with the computed model? I know there is a way to throttle binding, but is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: @Jarek: I was just spit-balling an idea there and really it's just a glorified version of my other idea and *I think* you'd still need a backing field for every value, so I'm not sure it'd save you anything. I'm not sure it could be made to work either since you need some external trigger (the clicking of the save or cancel button) to actually effect the writing (or not). Maybe a real KO expert (rather than somebody who's fiddle with it for about a month) has a better idea?

Comment: Thanks for you response, but Artem provided the KO method of doing it using a custom binding.